# How to get a list of names of Wi-Fi network

Tags: xamarin.android

How to get a list of names of Wi-Fi network and signal

I used the following method to fill the array.
It works on Android versions less than 5 only. and does not work on 6 or higher.
I want code that works on all versions.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />

List myListrow = new List();

        var wifiMgr = (WifiManager)GetSystemService(WifiService);
        var wifiList = wifiMgr.ScanResults;

        foreach (var item in wifiList)
        {
            var wifiLevel = WifiManager.CalculateSignalLevel(item.Level, 100);
             myListrow.Add(($"Wifi Name: {item.Ssid} - Single: {wifiLevel}"));

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

Add the `permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` permission. The original code works well.

The code used to list the all the names:

```
void getWifiList() {

        IList myListrow = new ArrayList();

        var wifiMgr = (WifiManager)GetSystemService(WifiService);
        var wifiList = wifiMgr.ScanResults;

        foreach (var item in wifiList)
        {
            var wifiLevel = WifiManager.CalculateSignalLevel(item.Level, 100);
            myListrow.Add(($"Wifi Name: {item.Ssid} - Single: {wifiLevel}"));

        }

    }
```

The code to request permission:

```
 private void RequestPermission()
    {
        Log.Info(TAG, " permission has NOT been granted. Requesting permission.");

        if (ActivityCompat.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.Permission.AccessCoarseLocation))
        {

            Snackbar.Make(layout, Resource.String.permission_accesscoarselocation_rationale,
                Snackbar.LengthIndefinite).SetAction(Resource.String.ok, new Action<View>(delegate (View obj) {
                    ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new String[] { Manifest.Permission.AccessCoarseLocation }, REQUEST_LOCATION);
                })).Show();
        }
        else
        {
            // AccessCoarseLocation permission has not been granted yet. Request it directly.
            ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new String[] { Manifest.Permission.AccessCoarseLocation }, REQUEST_LOCATION);
        }
    }
```

Screenshot:

[image]

You could download the source file from the link below.
https://github.com/WendyZang/Test/tree/master/Wi-Fi%20network/GetNetWorkInfo

Comment: Unfortunately wifiMgr.ScanResults doesn't refreshes the list even after some wifi AP are switched off. Only way to get the latest list is by killing the app and re-launching. Any idea what can be done to get the latest scan list everytime I run wifiMgr.ScanResults?